# trying to build this tutorial game from react js and not able to move forward

Tags: reactjs, jsx

this is my code so far by following official react js tutorial of making a tic-tac-toe game, I able to complete the game, but struct on the 1st challenge of create square using loop instead of hardcoding it, as you can see the comment part of code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick} >{value}</button>
    );
}

function CreateSquares(squares, handleClick) {

    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const rows = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            rows.push(
                <Square value={squares[j]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(j)} key={j} />
            );
        }
        data.push(
            <div className="board-row" key={i}>{rows}</div>
        );
    }
    return data;
}

function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {

    let winner = calculateWinner(squares);

    function handleClick(index) {
        if (squares[index] || winner) {
            return;
        }
        const nextSquares = squares.slice();

        nextSquares[index] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';

        onPlay(nextSquares);
    }
    let status = winner ? "Winner: " + winner : "Next Player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");

    return (
        <>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <CreateSquares squares={squares} handleClick={handleClick} />
            {/* <div className="board-row">
                <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
                <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
                <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
                <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
                <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
                <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
                <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
            </div> */}
        </>
    );
}

export default function Game() {
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
    const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
    const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
    const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

    function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
        const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
        setHistory(nextHistory);
        setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
    }

    function jumpTo(nextMove) {
        setCurrentMove(nextMove);
    }

    const moves = history.map((squares, move) => {
        let description = move > 0 ? 'Go to move #' + move : "Go to game start";

        return (
            <li key={move}>
                <button onClick={() => { jumpTo(move) }}>{description}</button>
            </li>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
                <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} squares={currentSquares} onPlay={handlePlay} />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
                <ol>{moves}</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    let len = lines.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

this is the error i'm getting and i'm not able to figure out how to fix this.

```
    handleClick is not a function
    TypeError: handleClick is not a function
    at onSquareClick (http://localhost:3000/main.9d076070d9e17e2c1932.hot-update.js:51:30)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10826:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10870:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10927:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10941:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15085:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15111:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15122:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15131:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15291:16
```

i'm trying to learn react and struct here, I already studied official quick start guide 2-3 times, but still not able to figure out what i am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it working and here is the working solution

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick} >{value}</button>
    );
}

function CreateSquares({ squares, checkClick }) {

    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const rows = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            const index = i * 3 + j; // Calculate a unique index for each square

            rows.push(
                <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => checkClick(index)} key={index} />
            );
        }
        data.push(
            <div className="board-row" key={i}>{rows}</div>
        );
    }
    return data;
}

function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {

    let winner = calculateWinner(squares);

    function handleClick(index) {

        if (squares[index] || winner) {
            return;
        }
        const nextSquares = squares.slice();

        nextSquares[index] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';

        onPlay(nextSquares);
    }
    let status = winner ? "Winner: " + winner : "Next Player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");

    return (
        <>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <CreateSquares squares={squares} checkClick={handleClick} />
        </>
    );
}

export default function Game() {
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
    const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
    const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
    const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

    function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
        const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
        setHistory(nextHistory);
        setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
    }

    function jumpTo(nextMove) {
        setCurrentMove(nextMove);
    }

    const moves = history.map((squares, move) => {
        let description = move > 0 ? 'Go to move #' + move : "Go to game start";

        return (
            <li key={move}>
                <button onClick={() => { jumpTo(move) }}>{description}</button>
            </li>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
                <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} squares={currentSquares} onPlay={handlePlay} />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
                <ol>{moves}</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    let len = lines.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I needed to pass

```
<CreateSquares squares={squares} checkClick={handleClick} />
```

and need to do this

```
function CreateSquares({ squares, checkClick }) {
```

instead of this

```
function CreateSquares( squares, checkClick ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function CreateSquares(squares, handleClick) {

    function checkClick(index) {
        handleClick(index);
    }
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const rows = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            rows.push(
                <Square value={squares[j]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(j)} key={j} />
            );
        }
        data.push(
            <div className="board-row" key={i}>{rows}</div>
        );
    }
    return data;
}
```

in this part of code i think you're incorrectly calling handleClick function ( i.e wrong index  being passed , instead you have to pass unique index for each square based on rows and col ).

try this and let me know :

```
function CreateSquares(squares, handleClick) {
  function checkClick(index) {
    handleClick(index);
  }

  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const rows = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      const index = i * 3 + j; // Calculate a unique index for each square
      rows.push(
        <Square
          value={squares[index]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)}
          key={index}
        />
      );
    }
    data.push(<div className="board-row" key={i}>{rows}</div>);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: the error is `handleClick is not a function`, i got your point that i'm not passing unique index which also going to create problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Move the handleClick function outside the Board component
function handleClick() {
  // Your code logic here
}

function Board() {
  // Board component code

  return (
    // JSX code
  );
}

// Rename the handleClick function to avoid type errors
const handleClickOutsideBoard = handleClick;

// Call the handleClickOutsideBoard function from outside the Board component
handleClickOutsideBoard();
```

In this code, we moved the `handleClick` function outside the `Board` component so that it can be accessed from outside. We also renamed the function to `handleClickOutsideBoard` to avoid any potential type errors. You can then call the `handleClickOutsideBoard` function from anywhere outside the Board component.

Comment: can you please explain a little more, I'm not able to understand your point.

Comment: It's about defining your function, you need to defined it outside function, otherwise you won't be able to call function from outside, `handleclick` function will be trapped in other function.